# How to backup custom fonts and packages

Tags: fonts, best-practices, mactex

I'm about to format my computer but I have installed a lot of TeX fonts and some useful TeX packages.

I'd like to backup them, especially the fonts, because it took me a long long time to install but I'm afraid of forgetting important folders / files. What are the best practises to do such a thing ?

I'm running under OSX with MacTeX

Any suggestion welcome, thanks !

Comment: You mean OTF/TTF fonts that you installed system-wide, i.e. accessible for all applications not just TeX, right?

Comment: My word was ambiguous. I meant TeX fonts. I usually use fontools to convert my OTF fonts but I don't know precisely which files are generated nor where. Thanks for asking :)

Comment: @PaulGessler If you say so... I'm not sure what fonttools does, though, so I don't know if this is right. (Or does the OP mean `lcdftypetools`?)

Comment: @PaulGessler It is just that `fonttools` could be anything. For example, there is a `python-fonttools` which converts OTF/TTF to XML. I don't suppose that's the reference here, but felt on unknown ground!

Answer (score 2):

*If you installed the fonts as traditional TeX fonts* i.e. you generated `.tfm` and `.map` files etc., *then you can back them up as part of backing up your personal and local TEXMF directories.*

Whether or not you have installed these particular things in these places, you probably want to back these up.

- The local tree will be `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` (unless you changed the default).
- To get the location of your personal TEXMF tree, run `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` in Terminal. (I know the location switched in a MacTeX update so I don't want to tell you the wrong location as I'm not on a Mac now.)

These should cover anything you've installed specially outside TeX Live itself.

I believe Finder has an option to archive a directory so you could do that for each of those locations.

## Off-Topic

Note that ***you should not format your disk without backing everything on it up***. It is far, far too easy to overlook something crucial.

Indeed, backing up only when about to format is not a good strategy either. You should backup regularly so that when your hard drive dies (*when* - not *if*), you do not lose more work than you can bear.

[If you can cope with losing a week's work, backup weekly. If you can cope only with losing an hour's work, you need to backup hourly.]

***Data you don't backup regularly is data you don't mind losing.***